# Method reference and Generics in Java-8

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I am facing issue with *method reference* combined with generic types.

We have code where we need to call a overloaded method, but it is failing with error:

> Cannot resolve value m1()

I have simplified my problem to make it clear where the problem lies.

The following code fails:

```
public class Test {
    void test() {
        // Getting error here
        setValue(C1::m1, Integer.ONE);
    }

    <E extends I1, T> void setValue(BiConsumer<E, T> cons, T value) {
    }
}

interface I1 {
}

class C1 implements I1 {
    void m1(Integer value) {
    }

    void m1(int value) {
    }
}
```

Can someone please why this is behaving like this ?

Kindly note this is not related to the question [Java 8 Method reference with generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717234/java-8-method-reference-with-generic-types)

Comment: no if I remove one of the methods it is working fine then

Comment: Thanks for reopening this question again ... :)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the type inference rules aren't "smart" enough to resolve the conflict between picking the right `m1` variant and generating the correct inferred type parameters to the `setValue` call (`B` and `BigDecimal` respectively).

I can't quite explain *why* this fails, but type inference has traditionally been an area with arcane, well-reasoned and un-intuitive rules, so I'm not very suprised.

You can work around this issue by adding a type witness (specifying which type parameters you want to call `setValue` with) at which point the compiler will pick the correct `m1` method:

```
this.<B,BigDecimal>setValue(B::m1, BigDecimal.ONE);
```

Comment: Seems I am not inline with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1